# Add item to ListView dynamically

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I can't seem to figure out how ListView works. I need to add an item to the ListView at runtime, just like this picture:

[image: Screenshot]

I'm not able to use a database, so the data must be in the adapter or in an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Try a search for "ListView ArrayAdapter". That should pull up quite a few basic and useful examples

Answer (score 3):

If you need to add a new item to a `ListView` after you have passed in your `ListAdapter`, simply add the new data to the underlying collection, and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your `ListAdapter` (Assuming you are using an adapter implementation derived from `BaseAdapter`).